# StrawberryShake multiple clients

Tags: graphql, blazor

I have set up my Backend as a multi module Spring Server with each module listening to another port. How can I configure the StrawberryShake Client in Blazor to work with both ports? I tried initializing it only with http://localhost/graphql but i always get the error that the computer does not allow me to connect. Adding another .graphqlrc.json was also not working since i would have two files with the same name. How can I address both ports of my backend server?